# How Do I Create A Dynamic Changing Menu In Wordpress?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, menu

I saw this page: http://www.sklostudio.com/

What's the easiest way to create this effect?

User does an action and it turns the menu a different color? I know the page was designed with Squarespace.

Answer (score 0):

It is a JavaScript function, when the user click on the slideshow arrow, the onclick function will trigger in the same time therefore the menu color changed.

One of the easiest way to do the text color changing thing is:

```
<script>

document.getElementById('change').onclick = changeColor;   

function changeColor() {
    document.body.style.color = "blue";
    return false;
}
```